# Pandas Datetime multi-index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For the following dataframe, each account may have a different rate each month.  I was trying to locate the rate to be used for a particular transaction.

E.g. if I am looking for the Rate_A for account one at 2018-01-20, I should be getting the -1.206412 value.

What would be the best way to locate this value?  I tried to use resample('D').ffill(), but get an error instead as it doesn't seem to work on multi-index.

Thanks

```
                    Rate_A    Rate_B    Rate_C
date     account                              
2018-01   one    -1.206412  0.132003  1.024180
          two     2.565646 -0.827317  0.569605
2018-02   one     1.431256 -0.076467  0.875906
          two     1.340309 -1.187678 -2.211372
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use[`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html), but it working with `DatetimeIndex` only, so first convert second level to column, and then create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.groupby('account').resample('D').ffill()
print (df.head())
                   account    Rate_A    Rate_B   Rate_C
account date                                           
one     2018-01-01     one -1.206412  0.132003  1.02418
        2018-01-02     one -1.206412  0.132003  1.02418
        2018-01-03     one -1.206412  0.132003  1.02418
        2018-01-04     one -1.206412  0.132003  1.02418
        2018-01-05     one -1.206412  0.132003  1.02418

a = df.loc[('one', '2018-01-20'), 'Rate_A']
print (a)
#account  date      
#one      2018-01-20   -1.206412
#Name: Rate_A, dtype: float64
```

Another solution without `resample` use [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing):

```
a = df.index.get_level_values('date')
b = df.index.get_level_values('account')

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([pd.to_datetime(a), b])
print (df)
                      Rate_A    Rate_B    Rate_C
date       account                              
2018-01-01 one     -1.206412  0.132003  1.024180
           two      2.565646 -0.827317  0.569605
2018-02-01 one      1.431256 -0.076467  0.875906
           two      1.340309 -1.187678 -2.211372


d = '2018-01-20'
a = df.loc[(d.rsplit('-', 1)[0], 'one'), 'Rate_A']
print (a)
date        account
2018-01-01  one       -1.206412
Name: Rate_A, dtype: float64

print (d.rsplit('-', 1)[0])
2018-01
```

And if date is datetime:

```
d = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-20')
print (d)
2018-01-20 00:00:00

a = df.loc[(d.strftime('%Y-%m'), 'one'), 'Rate_A']
print (a)
date        account
2018-01-01  one       -1.206412
Name: Rate_A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you so much, both solutions are working perfectly.